# Raspberry pi and Arduino mini 05 connection

Tags: raspbian, gpio, arduino

First of, I consider myself a real newbie when it comes to electronics and have my base knowledge in high level programing. So please have that in consideration in your answers.

I have a raspberry pi model B and a Arduino Mini 05 (http://store.arduino.cc/product/A000088).

What I want to do:

Upload my code to the arduino via arduino ide running on the raspberry, output digital sensor data from my arduino to my raspberry pi.

So, how do I connect the arduino properly (with tx/rx and power) to my raspberry pi and how do I "publish" my code to via tx/rx?

Simple Illustrations and charts is highly welcome.

Comment: Arduino Mini also comes with the same chip (ATmega328) as Arduino Mini Pro. There is a great tutorial about connecting Rpi & Arduino Pro Mini, Check out this [link](http://conoroneill.net/connecting-an-arduino-to-raspberry-pi-for-the-best-of-both-worlds/).
If you don't understand, I can also write a longer answer

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I will check it out and get back to you. Thanks!